# Graph theory algorithm to find vertex with out-degree 0 and in-degree (n-1)

Tags: graph-theory

I'm wondering how to determine whether a directed graph has a get-stuck vertex, which is defined as a vertex with in-degree n-1 and out-degree 0.

I guess the dumb way would be to print the in-degree and out-degree of every vertex in the graph, but that's O(m+n). I'm interested in an O(n) algorithm. Any ideas?

Thanks!!

Comment: Do you want to know *whether* there is such a vertex, or *which* vertices are like that?

Comment: @Beta Whether there is such a vertex

Comment: Wouldn't this just be an array walk looking for  (pseudo) count(in)>1 && out==null ? I think that is 0(n); even faster when it finds a match early. Is it not?

Comment: @krowe can you explain what you mean further?

Comment: I could be wrong about what your wanting but if you just want to find all of the end nodes you'd walk the tree and find everything with out==null . Those are end nodes. You seem to just be wanting end nodes here with the special requirement that they must have at least one parent node. Just walk the tree (meaning visit each node) and return false whenever a node is encountered with no out pointer set.

Comment: I don't see how you come to that, we aren't even considering the edges beyond weather or not they exist. No matter how many edges we have we are doing the same # of calculations.

Comment: Ok, but how could this be done if I use an adjacency matrix as input?

Answer (score 0):

(I assume that n is vertices and m is edges.)

Note that there is at most one get-stuck vertex in a graph.

Suppose we have an O(n) algorithm. If m is large, we must reach a conclusion without considering every edge.

If we conclude that the get-stuck vertex exists, we are asserting that no unconsidered edge leads out of it, which we can't know.

Therefore I don't think that O(n) is possible.

O(m) is pretty straightforward.

Comment: I know it's definitely possible

Comment: @AmazingVal: How can you know that? Suppose I give a graph consisting of two nodes {A,B}, and many edges. How can you put an upper limit on how many edges you will check before giving a verdict?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Beta, there is no way you can solve this problem by o(n), because you have to visit each edge at least once to verify that it is a get-stuck node.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in O(n) if you represent the directed graph with two adjacency list, one representing going into the node and another going out of the node.

```
In-list
A -> B, C
B -> D
C -> 
D -> C

Out-list
A -> 
B -> A
C -> A, D
D -> B
```

[image: Graphical Representation]

In this case vertex A is such a vertex in question.

This way you can check for each vertex `V` whether any `out_list[V].empty() && !in_list[V].empty()`

The cost here of course it takes more storage and more operations during inserts.